# Url Rewriting in Asp.Net core 3.0

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-webapi

In .Net Core web API I want the endpoints to work with both ways like : `/api/order` or `/order`

So I tried so many regex patterns for rewriting the url to except "api" but no luck yet.
In startup Configure :

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRewrite("^(?!api\\/).*$", "/api/$1", true)
       .AddRedirectToHttps();
 app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

I believe my approach could be wrong about this.

Order Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
```

Comment: Try `.AddRewrite("^(?:api/)?", "api/", true)`

Comment: Nope, did not work. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: That means you want something else than redirecting all requests to `/api/...`, right? If you need help with regex please explain what needs to be replaced with what.

Comment: Any endpoint should work both ways as above like in order endpoint. e.g. : `/api/order` or `/order`
So, I need to replace any request to `/api/<rest of request>` except it already has `/api`

Comment: Then my suggestion should work but for one thing: when the URL is `/api`. If it is the case, replace `^(?:api/)?` with `^(?:api(?:/|$))?`

Comment: Or, `.AddRewrite("^(?:api(/|$))?", "api$1", true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many tries, I've found the answer. If only Regex could be a bit easier.

```
.AddRewrite("^(?!api\\/)(.*)$", "api/$1", true)
```

`.*` needed to be in brackets and rewrite value did not need a preceeding forward slash.

Regex examples in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-6.0) made me find my own way.

In order to understand what goes behind the rewriter I needed to add another middleware to log incoming http requests. [Here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/) is a good article for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use two Route attributes instead of that single one...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
```

Will work, you could even setup a base controller class with those attributes and never have to deal with it again (I think)

Comment: I could try that but I have a health check middleware  `app.UseHealthChecks("/api/health");` which does not have a controller. It has to work the same way with others. So this is not an option. Thanks for the idea anyways.